# create an android app update functionality programatically?

Tags: android

This question may be silly but i am student and for my project i need this functionality. I know that app can be easily updated using playstore. But my app will not go on play store. It will be on dropbox or on my demo site. Whenever i update my app a dialogue box pop ups on user device showing that "your version: ***" and new "version available:***" with Update now ok button to download new version. I already tried a tut of juri's blog but did not work for me on android studio. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You have to maintain it from the server side (By calling the web service)...And make the check of the build current version with the server's response

Comment: check out this link. 
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-update-application.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement push notification.

When you upload a new app, you need to send push notification to device and ask user to update or not if update you can download the apk and install using Intent

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my app from server side. it can be done without push notification. you have to send app version from client to your server. and at server side you can check if the version from client is less then version at server side. you can send specific result code, and base on it you can ask user to update user or update it pro grammatically.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please share this code. I tried a tutorial before but not helped me.

Comment: do you have web services implemented in your app ?

Comment: Yes. This is online app

Comment: Can you please make a video tutorial related to this update functionality only. Not all the code of your app...

Comment: dear it is simple, you have to maintain a database table at server end which will have most recent version of the app

Comment: and when app will be opened at first API request e.g. login you can send app version in parameters

Comment: and then compare it with version in your database table and send response based on it.

Comment: have you checked link shared by waqas ali ?

Comment: Can you please do this?

Comment: A simple dialogue box to update the app when new version is available.

Comment: can you come to chat for discussion, is it paid or ?

Comment: For my college project. Free app.

Comment: can you create chat room here at stack overflow, or email me description. what are you working on, what you need.

Comment: What is your email address?

Comment: hammad.sahi@gmail.com